# How would mvc cause non-deterministic ui and redux not

Tags: model-view-controller, redux

I've read several articals as well as offical docs of redux all of which mention mvc leads to non-deterministic ui while redux not as redux uses pure function. I know that pure function produces same output for same input. But why mutation does not? It would be nice to have an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutation + asynchronous code can easily lead to functions that don't return the same result given the same input. This is a (very) simplified example with some comments.

```js
// this could be a function in your controller
function delayedAddition(valuePair) {
  console.log(
    `Getting ready to calculate ${valuePair.x} + ${valuePair.y}`
  );
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(valuePair.x + valuePair.y), 500);
  });
}
const printWithMessage = message => printMe => console.log(message, printMe);

let mutableValuePair = { x: 5, y: 10 };

// this could be a call your view depends on
delayedAddition(mutableValuePair)
 .then(printWithMessage('Result is: '));

// MUTATION! 
// This could happen in another controller,
// or where ever
mutableValuePair.x = 32;
// Expected result = 5 + 10.
// Result is:  42
// So your view is no longer a function of 
// what arguments you pass to your controllers.
```

If we were using an immutable data structure for `valuePair` then something like `valuePair.setX(32)` would not change the original object. Instead we'd get back a new (independent) copy. So you would use it like this instead `const modifiedValuePar = valuePair.setX(32)`. That way, the ongoing calculation (which used the unaffected `valuePair`) would still give the expected result that 5 + 10 =  15.